# Chrome distorts images

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

As you can see below, Chrome does not display images correctly (the gray enlarged picture should be entirely black).  The distortion is seemingly chosen at random, but occurs frequently.  Sometimes the images are rendered grey, sometimes it's flipped upside down, sometimes a completely different image (on same webpage or previously visited) takes its place.  Firefox does not have this problem.

[image]

Comment: Does disabling hardware acceleration help?

Comment: @edwinksl That seemed to fix it actually.  If you want to make an answer post, I can accept it.  I think the issue is with my graphics card/driver.  I have an Nvidia GeForce GT 650M.  My current driver is open-source Nouveau, which probably isn't optimal.  Changing to the latest Nvidia driver does fix the Chrome image distorting, but the crucial downside is that it causes a black screen upon booting.

Comment: You can edit grub by typing `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` in a terminal and remove the two parameters `quiet splash` from the corresponding line.  Just leave the quotes without anything in between.  Type `sudo update-grub` after you save the changes.  On the next reboot you will see the startup sequence scrolling on your screen but the screen won't shut down like it does now.

Comment: @onepiece Sounds good, I will write a quick one. If you can figure out how to prevent that black screen upon booting, you should write an answer too so others who may have this problem can have more things to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with a lot of issues related to graphics in Chrome, disabling hardware acceleration is commonly suggested as a workaround and fixes the problem of image distortion in this case.